# automatically play next soundcloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, widget, soundcloud

I'm currently working on my music blog, and I'm trying to make the widgets start when previous one finishes. I have both soundcloud and youtube widgets, but the priority is to implement this functionality for the soundcloud ones.

Each iframe has 2 class .widget &.soundcloud_widget for soundcloud and .widget & .youtube_widget for youtube. Finally, each widget gets an id "widget1", "widget2", etc... in the order of apparition.

The idea would be to get the event "SC.Widget.Events.FINISH" , to get the id of the corresponding widget, "increment" it, and then make the next one play.

Unfortunately, I'm struggling with javascript & the documentation of soundcloud, and I would really appreciate some help !

Thanks in advance

PS : here is the code that does the above, I have nothing else that is usable...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function autoPlayInitiate () {
        var i=1; 
        $("iframe[src^='https://w.soundcloud.com/']").addClass("widget soundcloud_widget"); 
        $("iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']").addClass("widget youtube_widget");
        $('.widget').each(function(){
          $(this).attr('id','widget'+i);
          i++;
        }); 
    }
    window.onload = autoPlayInitiate;

     $(document).ready(function () { 
       var ScWidget = $('.soundcloud_widget');
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post some code so we can help you

Comment: I put what I have which is basically nothing : just the function that gives the right classes & id to iframes.
The fact is I don't even know where to start : I can declare individually each widget as a soundcloud widget as explained in the documentation, but how to say to watch events for each one ?

Answer (score 0):

So first off I think the simplest way for you to solve this problem is to pick one of the players (either youtube or soundcloud) and use there playlist features to showcase your sounds.
here is a live example of using a playlist in Sound Cloud you can play with 

http://runnable.com/UuhEs3Yq2_8hAACT/embbed-soundcloud-widget-using-javascript 

relevant code:

```
function embed (id) {
  SC.oEmbed("http://soundcloud.com/" + id // user or playlist to embed
    , { color: "ff0066"
      , auto_play: true
      , maxwidth: 500
      , maxheight: 1000
      , show_comments: true } // options
    , document.getElementById("scWidget") // what element to attach player to
  );
}

$(document).ready(
  function () {
    embed("dj-faze");
  }
);
```

however if you wish to go the long route you will want to familiarize yourself with the widget API:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#

the bind(eventName, listener) is what you would be most interested in

```
var iframeElement   = document.querySelector('iframe');
var iframeElementID = iframeElement.id;
var widget         = SC.Widget(iframeElement);
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function () {
  alert('add code to play next song here')
});
```

I will try to put up a new example on runnable once the site has finished its maintenance

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I will take a further look at it in a few hours and give you feedback, thks again!